# Rails 5 Autocomplete - send id to model instead of autocomplete field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-5, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have implemented a Rails form autocomplete system just like the one in this cast [Autocomplete with HTML results](https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/autocomplete-with-html-results). The issue is: I need to get the id of the object chosen in the autocomplete suggestions because it is my foreign key, and I can only get the text chosen.`<%= f.text_field :concelho_id, class: 'autocomplete form-control', data: { source: autocomplete_concelhos_path } %>`

I tried changing the result_value to id instead of name, but that writes automatically the id in the input field when the suggestion is chosen. I don't want that, as it confuses the user.

```
module Autocomplete
  class Concelhos < ApplicationAutocomplete

    private

    def result_partial(concelho)
      ApplicationController.new.render_to_string(partial: 'concelhos/autocomplete', locals: { concelho: concelho }).html_safe
    end

    def result_value(concelho)
      concelho.name
    end

    def results
      @results ||= Concelho.where('name LIKE :query', query: "%#{params[:term]}%").limit(5)
    end

  end
end
```

How can I get this id to pass to the model params? I tried hidden fields and changing the model autocomplete class but with no success. I also thought about remote form_tags to work with params, but I guess that demands a submit button, which I don't wish either. I also don't know if a fields_for approach would work for this kind of issue. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with this too.
In your model, try something like this.

```
def self.text_search(query)
  if query.present?
      where("name @@ :q, q: query)
  else
      @concelho = Concelho.all
  end
end
```